# How to check a text in HTML content using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check a particular word/text in HTML content using jQuery.
For eg: 
Let my html content be

```
<p>I Love StackOverFlow</p>
```

So how can I check & highlight the sentence if it contains the word 'Love'?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery.contains()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p:contains('Love')").css("background-color","red");
});
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: +1 best solution. also correct with quoting the text with `''`

Answer (score 2):

Use the contains selector - http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/